# OpenGL output of simple vertex shader OK but results in a black screen

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, shader, glfw

Yes, this is another "Black screen in OpenGL, help!" post. I have done my due diligence, here is what I have tried so far to diagnose:

- Checking for any and all errors during my window initialization with GLAD/GLFW
- Checking for any shader errors during compilation and program linking
- Checking for GL errors after every single GL command in the entire app.
- Using Renderdoc to examine the list of gl commands being executed.
- Using glClear to clear the color of the screen (Yes, this works totally fine, so presumably the context is OK)

My program is a dead simple one that sets up a buffer to render a triangle (Actually there's much more scaffolding since this is adapted from a previous renderer I had in d3d11, but I pared it down and down until it was basically just tutorial code). In Renderdoc you can see the vertex positions coming through no problem, and it seems to understand that the fragment shader is linked and executing as well, yet all I see is a black screen.

If anybody knows any gotchas or debugging steps, please by all means throw your ideas at me. I'll post my main rendering code, shaders, and a couple screens from renderdoc so you can see I'm not crazy. Also I know there's some stuff in here that wouldn't make sense to do per-frame. This is just as bare bones simple as I could get it to sanity check. My shader loading code and window init code is bog standard so I won't bother to post it, but if anybody thinks it would help to see I'm happy to.

**main loop**

```
    glViewport(0, 0, 300, 300); 
    ASSERT(glGetError() == GL_NO_ERROR);


    GLuint VertexArrayID;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &VertexArrayID); 
    ASSERT(glGetError() == GL_NO_ERROR);
    glBindVertexArray(VertexArrayID); 
    ASSERT(glGetError() == GL_NO_ERROR);

    static const GLfloat g_vertex_buffer_data[] = {
       -1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,
       1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,
       0.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f,
    };

    GLuint vertexbuffer;
    glGenBuffers(1, &vertexbuffer);
    ASSERT(glGetError() == GL_NO_ERROR);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexbuffer);
    ASSERT(glGetError() == GL_NO_ERROR);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(g_vertex_buffer_data), g_vertex_buffer_data, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    ASSERT(glGetError() == GL_NO_ERROR);

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    ASSERT(glGetError() == GL_NO_ERROR);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexbuffer);
    ASSERT(glGetError() == GL_NO_ERROR);
    glVertexAttribPointer(
        0,           
        3,             
        GL_FLOAT,     
        GL_FALSE,      
        0,         
        (void*)0     
    );
    ASSERT(glGetError() == GL_NO_ERROR);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3); 
    ASSERT(glGetError() == GL_NO_ERROR);
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
    ASSERT(glGetError() == GL_NO_ERROR);

    glfwPollEvents();
    glfwSwapBuffers(glfwGetCurrentContext());
```

**vert shader**

```
#version 330 core
layout(location = 0) in vec3 inPos;
layout(location = 0) out vec4 outPos;

void main(){
  outPos.xyz = inPos;
  outPos.w = 1.0;
}
```

**frag shader**

```
#version 330 core
layout(location = 0) out vec3 color;
void main(){
  color = vec3(1,0,0);
}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write the `gl_Position` in the vertex shader. `gl_Position` cannot be replaced with a custom output variable (like `gl_FragColor` in the fragment shader):

```c
#version 330 core
layout(location = 0) in vec3 inPos;

void main()
{
    gl_Position.xyz = vec4(inPos, 1.0);
}
```

See [OpenGL Shading Language 4.60 Specification - 7.1.1. Vertex Shader Special Variables](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/GLSLangSpec.4.60.html#built-in-language-variables)

Note, the outputs of the vertex shader are inputs to the next shader stage (in your case the fragment shader), but the vertex position (`gl_Position`) is required for following steps in the [Rendering Pipeline](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Rendering_Pipeline_Overview).

Comment: Perfectly correct, thank you for the answer. Spent way too long on that, should have just gone over the spec!